# Best approach for extending unobtrusive javascript in MVC3 to add a style to a div client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, razor, unobtrusive-validation, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using html5/Razor/MVC3 leveraging the Bootstrap template from Twitter. I want to have form validation that looks slick like they've documented (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#forms). So if we take a look at how the standard boiler-plate MVC3 for account registration, the markup would look like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="form-stacked" })) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Snap! Something went wrong")
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>
            <div class="clearfix error">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                <div class="input">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                    <span class="help-inline">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                <div class="input">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
                    <span class="help-inline">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                <div class="input">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                    <span class="help-inline">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                <div class="input">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                    <span class="help-inline">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="actions">
            <button class="btn large primary" type="submit">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I want to do is have the container div inject the "error" class like I've hard-coded in the first input. (So upon entering the page, the div would have a class of "clearfix" but if that input block failed validation, it would tag it as "clearfix error"). I figure I'm going to have to update the div block to include an id of some sort and perhaps add a new data- attribute to the ValidationMessage. I don't have a problem extending the ValidationMessageFor helper. I'm just not 100% sure what the approach should be for extending the library that's there. Any suggestions on how to approach this?

TIA.

**UPDATE**:

I am thinking this approach is reasonable:

```
<div id="UserNameContainer" class="clearfix error">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
    <div class="input">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
        <span class="help-inline">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, null, new { @data_container = "UserNameContainer" })</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

By decorating my validation message with a data-container name, I could then target the container div. Now I just need to figure out how to intercept the validation message.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: So @JBright, did you solve this or did one of these answer the question?

Answer (score 52):

The `$.validator.setDefaults` method solved this issue for me with Bootstrap from Twitter. I'm using`jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`.

Since unobtrusive validation on DOM ready scans your document and caches unobtrusive validation options for each form it encounters, it is needed to call the `$.validator.setDefaults` method before document scan occurs.

```
// setup defaults for $.validator outside domReady handler
$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest(".clearfix").addClass("error");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest(".clearfix").removeClass("error");
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
       // do other stuff
});
```

Comment: If you also like server errors highlighted use something like `$('form .input-validation-error').closest(".clearfix").addClass("error");` on document ready.

Answer (score 4):

Came accross the same issue. I am tackling it by adding and extesion to the HtmlHelper Class.

This is what I did for the ValidationSummary:

```
   public static class TwitterBootstrapHelperExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString BootstrapValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper helper,
                               bool excludePropertyErrors,
                               string message)
        {
            if(helper.ViewData.ModelState.Values.All(v => v.Errors.Count == 0)) return new MvcHtmlString(string.Empty);

            string errorsList = "<ul>";
            foreach (var error in helper.ViewData.ModelState.Values.Where(v => v.Errors.Count >0))
            {
                errorsList += string.Format("<li>{0}</li>", error.Errors.First().ErrorMessage);
            }
            errorsList += "</ul>";
            return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("<div class=\"alert-message error\"><span>{0}</span>{1}</div>",message,errorsList));

        }
    }
```

And in the .cshtml file I replace Html.ValidationSummary with this:

```
@Html.BootstrapValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
```

Remember to add the namespance of your extension class in the views folder web.config file.

I will post here later if I tackle the individual input item before you.
HTH

Comment: I did something similar--a "BootstrapValidationSummary" that could optionally be used. My code is pretty close to my original update, but I like what Germán proposed with jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reinventing this particular wheel, check the validationEngine plugin available at http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/.

You can customize the popup elements as you want, and it is trivial to connect to jQuery.validate.js.

Answer (score 1):

I prefere to change the CSS of bootstrap.
Just added the classes of jQuery validate in the right place.
field-validation-error and input-validation-error

```
    form .clearfix.error > label, form .clearfix.error .help-block, form .clearfix.error .help-inline, .field-validation-error {
  color: #b94a48;
}
form .clearfix.error input, form .clearfix.error textarea, .input-validation-error {
  color: #b94a48;
  border-color: #ee5f5b;
}
form .clearfix.error input:focus, form .clearfix.error textarea:focus, .input-validation-error:focus {
  border-color: #e9322d;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #f8b9b7;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #f8b9b7;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #f8b9b7;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate MVC3 validation with Bootstrap framework by adding the following javascript to your page (View)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
/* Bootstrap Fix */
$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest("div.control-group").addClass("error");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest("div.control-group").removeClass("error");
    }
});
var current_div;
$(".editor-label, .editor-field").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass("editor-label")) {
        current_div = $('<div class="control-group"></div>').insertBefore(this);
    }
    current_div.append(this);
});
$(".editor-label").each(function () {
    $(this).contents().unwrap();
});
$(".editor-field").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("controls");
    $(this).removeClass("editor-field");
});
$("label").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("control-label");
});
$("span.field-validation-valid, span.field-validation-error").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("help-inline");
});
$("form").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("form-horizontal");
    $(this).find("div.control-group").each(function () {
        if ($(this).find("span.field-validation-error").length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass("error");
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Besides, on the Views (for example "Create.cshtml") make sure that the fields in the form are formatted as the following...

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Name)
    </div>
```

With this solution, it will most likely be enough to just add a javascript without edit the View.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is taken the css classes for the validation errors and created a new css file with the same classes but with bootstrap values.

You can find it in a nuget package at: http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MahApps.Twitter.Bootstrap

That also provides some scaffolding templates to autocreate new views.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to solve this using Bootstrap 3.1 and Razor.  This is what I used:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).parents(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).parents(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
    }
});

$(function () {

    $('span.field-validation-valid, span.field-validation-error').each(function () {
        $(this).addClass('help-block');
    });

    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $(this).find('div.form-group').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length == 0) {
                    $(this).removeClass('has-error');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('div.form-group').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length > 0) {
                    $(this).addClass('has-error');
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('form').each(function () {
        $(this).find('div.form-group').each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length > 0) {
                $(this).addClass('has-error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is a combination of @german's answer and help from this [post](http://www.braindonor.net/blog/integrating-bootstrap-error-styling-with-mvcs-unobtrusive-error-validation/381/) by "theBraindonor".  Updated to use new Bootstrap 3 classes.