# Cannot break on jquery.validate callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, jquery-validate, firebug

I'm using Firefox/Firebug, trying to step through some of the jquery.validate() callbacks.

Why do breakpoints on the below `// Breakpoint` lines not trigger upon clicking the submit button?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/library/scripts/lib/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/" method="post">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="This is required" id="BirthDate" 
           name="BirthDate" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="BirthDate" 
          data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" /></p>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('form').validate({
                debug: true,
                submitHandler: function () {
                    alert("Submitted!") // Breakpoint
                },
                invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
                    alert("Invalid!") // Breakpoint
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

Actually, it doesn't seem like any of the validate() options are taking effect.  For example, I've added `debug: true` to the example above, and per the documentation it's supposed to prevent the form from being submitted, and it's still submitting the form.  None of the alerts are fired either.

However, I have confirmed that the validate() function is getting called, because I can step through that -- just not the callbacks.

Comment: If you can step through the validate function, can you see that the callbacks are used there somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the jquery.validate() options don't seem to function [when used in combination with unobtrusive validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8036546/213902).  Removing that reference from my file fixes the issue, but of course, breaks my unobtrusive validation.

So I ended up using [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7716147/213902) to hook into the validation events.